# Predict probability on AWS SageMaker AutoPilot endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am testing SageMaker AutoPilot in order to verify how good it is for regular use.

Up until now, it seems relatively easy to use it, it trained a model with good results and it was easy to create the endpoint. I would like to get the predicted label and its probability, in order to check if the prediciton is good. However, I could only get the label and I did not find anything about retrieving the probability (predict_proba).

Is there any way to get the probability? Thank you!

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you happen to get any info on this?

Comment: Not yet! If I get any info about this, I will post here. If you get any way to get the probability, please post here! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can now get select the inference response for classification models :)

More info at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/autopilot-automate-model-development-container-output.html

Answer (score 1):

When creating your endpoint model, the environment variables: `SAGEMAKER_INFERENCE_OUTPUT` and `SAGEMAKER_INFERENCE_INPUT` must be set in each container in the container list. Valid values are: `'predicted_label, probabilit(y)(ies),labels'`

See the following to understand the container configuration: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model

And the link Julien posted has some good, but incomplete information as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/autopilot-automate-model-development-container-output.html